# MDX new measure based on two derived measures

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have two calculated MDX measures based on units and discount. I need to calculate sum of units for each discount value. 
I need to perform this calculation only in MDX (2008). Similar to sum over( partition by discount) in SQL.

Example

**Product Disc   Units  SumofUnits**

- Mango   5%       10    15
- Apple   5%       5     15
- Apple   7%       8     18
- Apple   7%      10     18

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more details about your cube structure? Do you have the Discount attribution? If so, you have to run the following:

```
SUM(
    [Discount].[Discount].[Discount].Members,
    [Measures].[Disc]
)
```

Comment: In cube structure, its available as a measure only.  I am not able to use it in  members function. Discount measure changes periodically over time, so cant keep it as attribute.

Comment: You can add a measure with SUM aggregation in order to sum a measure. I can't help you more without knowing your cube structure and seeing your wished output.

Comment: Product is an attribute in cube. Discounts and units in the example are derived measures, now I am asked to calculate sum of units based on the discount value.                                                                                                

Example
**Product (attribute)     Disc  (Measure)  Units (Measure)    SumofUnits(Req Output)**

Please refer the example for values. Please help

Comment: Try ([Product].[Product].[All], [Measures].[Units]) as SumofUnits.

Comment: That will provide sum of all products. I need the output grouped based on discount measure, see first two rows is 5% discount and Sum of units (output) for first two rows is (5 units +10 units ) =15, next two rows is 7% discount and sum of units for next two rows is (8 units +10 units) =18.

Comment: The best practice: you have to add an Disc dimension and use the Disc attribution on axes with [Measures].[Units].

Comment: Discount is a derived measure and it changes for product over time. So wont be able to add it as dimension.

Comment: Could you please provide the Discount measure code?